# SQL: Nested Case in ORDER BY Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to nest a case statement into another in the ORDER BY section of my query. Here is what I got:

```
ORDER BY 

CASE WHEN v.Interior = 'MEL (White - 113)' AND v.Interior = 'MEL 290 (Maple)' 
THEN v.[Finish] ELSE

( CASE
        WHEN v.[Item] like 'Adjustable%'  THEN v.[Item]                 
        WHEN v.[Item] Like 'Fixed%'       THEN v.[Item]
        WHEN v.[Item] like '%Divider%'    THEN v.[Item]
        END DESC)

,v.[Finish], v.[W mm] DESC

END
```

But Doing this gives me an error. I have also tried:

```
ORDER BY 

CASE WHEN v.Interior = 'MEL (White - 113)' AND v.Interior = 'MEL 290 (Maple)' 
THEN v.[Finish] END

,CASE
        WHEN v.[Item] like 'Adjustable%'  THEN v.[Item]         
        WHEN v.[Item] Like 'Fixed%'       THEN v.[Item]
        WHEN v.[Item] like '%Divider%'    THEN v.[Item]
        END DESC

,v.[Finish], v.[W mm] DESC
```

But this does not order the results the way I need.

Here is the result I get when error is fixed:

[image]

But the above results do not obey the first case statement. I can not order by LEVEL either as it causes problem when I export the result to another program.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Grateful for your help in advance!

Comment: DESC must be specified outside the CASE expression.

Comment: Thank you for reply @jarlh I tried that but still nothing

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: A case expression returns a value, it's not used for conditional code.

Comment: How can that condition be ever true? "CASE WHEN v.Interior = 'MEL (White - 113)' AND v.Interior = 'MEL 290 (Maple)' "

Comment: @MJXBoz the point is that it can never be true as Interior can't be MEL (White - 113) and MEL 290 (Maple) at the same time. Most probably you would like to use OR instead of AND or change it to Interior IN (...)

Comment: You have 2 cases statements and only 1 end statement as well; or the end statement is misplaced.  `ORDER BY CASE WHEN v.Interior = in ('MEL 290 (Maple)', 'MEL (White - 113)') 
              THEN v.[Finish] ELSE CASE WHEN v.[Item] like 'Adjustable%'  THEN v.[Item]                 
                                        WHEN v.[Item] Like 'Fixed%'       THEN v.[Item]
                                        WHEN v.[Item] like '%Divider%'    THEN v.[Item]
                                   END 
         END DESC
    , v.[Finish]
    , v.[W mm] DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Between the two queries, you fixed one problem but created another.   It's best to only change one thing at a time.

Try this:

```
ORDER BY 

CASE 
  WHEN v.Interior = 'MEL (White - 113)' AND v.Interior = 'MEL 290 (Maple)' 
  THEN v.[Finish] 
  ELSE CASE
        WHEN v.[Item] like 'Adjustable%'  THEN v.[Item]                 
        WHEN v.[Item] Like 'Fixed%'       THEN v.[Item]
        WHEN v.[Item] like '%Divider%'    THEN v.[Item]
        ELSE NULL --need to have some default if all cases are false.
  END DESC
END   
,v.[Finish], v.[W mm] DESC
```

This should at least not error, but whether it does what you want isn't clear from the attempts in your question.

Comment: check the first case statement. It is given by OP but anyway it is not right

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev, well that's true.   Which makes the last sentence in my answer especially poigniant.   This fixes the errors, but it's not clear what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thank you for your reply! And sorry for the confusion. I just added the result I get with that in my question.

Comment: @MJXBoz "But the above results do not obey the first case statement."   The first case statement can never be true, so it DOES obey it by ignoring it.   Now what you actually meant for the first case statement to be, I have no idea.   It's not clear.   Did you maybe mean for that AND to be an OR instead?

Comment: @TabAlleman Thank you for your reply again! in my result I have both white and 290 for interior. But often times I have only either of the two as a result for interior. That is when I want the query to Order by the second Case statement. Sorry for the confusion again. I am new to SQL and the Stackflow community.

Comment: No, you don't.   You have some rows that have white, and some rows that have 290, but you don't have any single row that has both white AND 290.  It's not possible.  I think you're trying to say something else, but it's still not clear.

Comment: @TabAlleman Right. my apologies again. Yes I am trying to say when there are some rows that are 290 and some rows that are white then run the first case statement. When only 290 or only white then second case statement.

Comment: Ok then what you need is more complex.  I can't show you without seeing your entire query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte, for example

```
With cte(
Select CASE WHEN v.Interior = 'MEL (White - 113)' AND v.Interior = 'MEL 290 (Maple)' 
THEN v.[Finish] ELSE

( CASE
        WHEN v.[Item] like 'Adjustable%'  THEN v.[Item]                 
        WHEN v.[Item] Like 'Fixed%'       THEN v.[Item]
        WHEN v.[Item] like '%Divider%'    THEN v.[Item]
        END DESC) as 'Columnname'

,v.[Finish], v.[W mm]
From Yourtablename)
Select *
From cte
Order By Columnname, Finish, [W mm] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your case statement in parenthesis with the order direction outside of your parenthesis like so:

```
ORDER BY 

(CASE WHEN v.Interior = 'MEL (White - 113)' OR v.Interior = 'MEL 290 (Maple)' 
 THEN v.[Finish]
 ELSE
     (CASE WHEN v.[Item] like 'Adjustable%'  THEN v.[Item]                 
           WHEN v.[Item] Like 'Fixed%'       THEN v.[Item]
           WHEN v.[Item] like '%Divider%'    THEN v.[Item]
           ELSE '' --Use '' as default. An empty order by will not affect your final result
      END) 
END) DESC
,v.[Finish]
,v.[W mm] DESC
```